# Rails relationships in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model -

```
class Donor < ActiveRecord::Base #recipient has name:string email:string
  has_one :recipient
end

class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base #recipient has name:string address:string 
end
```

The donors are already populated in the database.

I have the following route -

```
   match "/:donor" =>"pages#donation", :as => :donor
```

In that action I have the following -

```
    @donor = Donor.find_by_name(params[:donor])
```

The donors names are already in the database.

And in the view I have -

```
<%= form_for @donor do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, "Name" %> #this is prepopulated with their name - but they can change it.
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"input-text" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I add fields to add the recipients details to that form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need nested form. Have a look, for example, at [this](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) great article.

Comment: Thanks! accepts_nested_attributes_for is what I was looking for.